# Ignore case on user log in

Tags: php, lowercase, login-script

I have a simple PHP login script that compares the user and password to an array. The array is in lower case. Is there an easy way to convert the users input to lower case regardless of how they input it. As in.. Ralph gets converted to ralph

My login code where I would hope to add the code to ignore the case. Or does it need to be done in the array.
Thank you for your time and my apologies if this question "is not well received" I try my best.

```
if ($_GET['user']) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
}
if ($_POST['user']) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}
```

That worked perfectly, now dare I ask, can it be made to work with a form? If my users forget their login details they can input their email address and if it exists in my array an email is sent back with their login details.

```
   <form action="../pages/send_mail.php" method="post">
    <table width="470" border="0" cellpadding="3">
     <tr>

    <td height="117" colspan="3"><left>
    <font size="+2"><b>Please type in your email address as listed in the Shareholders list</b>
    <span style="color:red; font-size: 125%; font-weight: bold;">
    </span></center></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
        <td width="250"><b>Email address&nbsp; &nbsp; &gt;&gt;&gt;</b></td>
        <td width="300"><input type="text" name="email_address" />
        &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><b></b>&nbsp;<br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Click this bar to have an email sent to the address above with your username and password " style="font-size:11px;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function.

Example:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['user']) {
    $user = strtolower($_GET['user']);
    $password = $_GET['password'];
}
if ($_POST['user']) {
    $user = strtolower($_POST['user']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from members 
where BINARY username= BINARY '$username' and BINARY password= BINARY '$password'
```

You can also use `BINARY` in your mysql query,to ignore upper and lowercase.

Comment: Sadly, my skills do not allow me to use a mysql. I know I should do it, have read many "how to's" on it. My static login works just fine, it is for a limited number of family members.. and I am afraid to screw up what I have.